# where we find imagick for windows and imagick extension php_imagick.dll that compatible to wamp 2.5?

Tags: imagick

I already tried install imagick in windows, but always failed,

> php startup unable to load dinamic library,
>   'c/wamp/.../php_imagick.dll'-%1 is not valid win 32

where we find imagick for windows and imagick extension php_imagick.dll that compatible to wamp 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

How about the official site?

http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.3.0rc1/
http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/

Comment: I already tried..
I have tried and restart my wamp server no problem,
but imagick does not visible in php info...

how the solution?